# using curl to make an api POST (debug help)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, curl

I am trying to test if my API is working. To do this I am running the following line of code:

`mftaff:~/workspace (api-controller) $ curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Origin: https://interstellar-wiki-mftaff.c9users.io" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"name":"foobar"}' https://blocmetrics-mftaff.c9users.io:8080/api/events |& tee -a output.txt`

However, when I run this I am receiving the following output to the console:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 104.197.98.45...
* Connected to blocmetrics-mftaff.c9users.io (104.197.98.45) port 8080 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [data not shown]
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [data not shown]
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
{ [data not shown]
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
{ [data not shown]
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
{ [data not shown]
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
} [data not shown]
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
} [data not shown]
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [data not shown]
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
{ [data not shown]
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [data not shown]
* SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
* Server certificate:
*    subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; OU=EssentialSSL Wildcard; CN=*.c9users.io
*    start date: 2016-10-17 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2017-11-01 23:59:59 GMT
*    subjectAltName: blocmetrics-mftaff.c9users.io matched
*    issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=COMODO CA Limited; CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /api/events HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: blocmetrics-mftaff.c9users.io:8080
> Accept: application/json
> Origin: https://interstellar-wiki-mftaff.c9users.io
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 17
> 
} [data not shown]
* upload completely sent off: 17 out of 17 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< cache-control: no-cache
< x-request-id: d62f648d-a901-4029-be1b-08aa65cc4b92
< x-runtime: 0.008397
* Server WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.3.0/2015-12-25) is not blacklisted
< server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.3.0/2015-12-25)
< date: Fri, 24 Mar 2017 08:18:39 GMT
< content-length: 61
< X-BACKEND: apps-proxy
< 

 21    78    0     0  100    17      0     12  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--    12{ [data not shown]

100    78  100    61  100    17     42     11  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--    42
* Connection #0 to host blocmetrics-mftaff.c9users.io left intact
{"error":"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."}
```

I am quite new to all this... and I do not know how to make heads or tails of this output in terms of identifying where/what is going wrong.

What I know so far:
There is some kind of failure/error going on, because a new event (which is the goal of this API POST) is not created.
I am signed in to the host website and the origin website, so that last line about a sign in error is confusing.

Any help identifying where the error may lay would be superb!

(If the reader feels he needs more info, please leave a comment, and I will happily supply it!)

Comment: Being signed in via the browser will only keep the cookie in your browser. The curl is entirely separate and you'll need some sort of authorization token to be sent in the request.

Comment: `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized` means lack of HTTP authorization, see curl's `--user` and friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see at the bottom

```
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

And lower

```
{"error":"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."}
```

The 401 part is the web server sending you a status code telling you that you are not authorized to view the content, ie. you aren't logged in or are not using proper http auth credentials.
As @DanielStenberg says in the comments, you can set the http auth creds using curl's `-u`. You can type `man curl` to see more options.
But this might also mean that you need to log in and have the proper cookies so you need to talk to whoever is running the app and find out what is necessary.

The `{"error": "You need..."}` part is the actual response body you're getting from the server. This is a JSON string like what you asked for in the `-H "Accept: application/json"` of your curl call.

So you need to "log in" first.

For a shorter output that will be easier for you to read, you can leave out the `-v` of your curl command, though it is packed with great info.

Comment: Thanks for providing such a detailed answer!